# Where does swagger_yard place the JSON it generates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-ui

Where does swagger_yard place the JSON file it generates?

It doesn't say so in the README, https://github.com/livingsocial/swagger_yard

I'm trying to point [swagger-ui_rails](https://github.com/d4be4st/swagger-ui_rails) to that JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my JSON in following `https://myapibaseurl.com/swagger/swagger` and pointing from the ui to this route was a success for me :).

You can check it by searching swagger in the output of `rails routes` console command to make sure where to look !

Comment: It's been a while since I had this question, and I have no way of verifying if this answer works for me, but I'll presume it does and mark it as the correct answer. :)

Comment: I saw the date after answering it yes, hope it'll help any other lost souls :) Thanks @Magne !